# Firefox shows connection reset error when server closes connection

Tags: python, sockets

I have created a simple python server that sends back everything it receives.

I wonder if it would be possible to close the connection immediately after sending the data to the client (web browser), and the client then displays the data it has received. Currently, the client displays **The connection was reset**.

Thanks

```py
#!/user/bin/env python3
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'  # loopback interface address 
PORT = 3000         # non-privileged ports are > 1023

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        # connect to the next client in queue
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            print(data)
            conn.sendall(data.encode())
```

Comment: Yes, you can close the connection immediately after sending the data to the client.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The server can close the connection, but the client displays connect was reset instead of displaying the response.

Comment: Then the client is buggy, but I don't see any client code here.

Comment: Well of course both client and server must follow the same protocol. If you don't one or both sides will report an error, just like what's happening here. HTTP is a complicated protocol and your server is not doing anything remotely close to HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```py
#!/user/bin/env python3
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'  # loopback interface address 
PORT = 3000         # non-privileged ports are > 1023

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        # connect to the next client in queue
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connected by', addr)
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        print(data)
        conn.sendall(data.encode())
        conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) # changed
```

### Explanation

The solution uses `conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` which sends a `FIN` signal instead of `conn.close()` which sends a `RST` signal.

We don't want to force the connection to close. TCP setup is expensive, so the browser would ask the server to keep the connection alive to query assets, and in this example the browser asks for `style.css`.

`RST` confuses the browser, and Firefox will show you "connection reset" error.

> FIN says: "I finished talking to you, but I'll still listen to everything you have to say until you say that you're done."
>
> RST says: "There is no conversation. I won't say anything and I won't listen to anything you say."
> from [FIN vs RST in TCP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049828/fin-vs-rst-in-tcp-connections)

Here is the Wireshark capture of using `shutdown`, we see that both the server at `3000` and the browser acknowledged each other's `FIN`.
[image]

When using `close`, we see that
[image]

A better option would be to wait for the client to initiate the 4 way finalization by programming the server to shut down the socket when the client signals `FIN`.

The 4 way finalization

[image]
From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-connection-termination/